# Pyviz Panel app.show() Does Not Work When Using Jupyter Notebook Remotely

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, ssh-tunnel, pyviz

I installed Anaconda on a CentOS VM on an Ubuntu server. I then created a conda environment for all of my python data science libraries on this VM. I have a matching conda environment on my laptop.

I then followed this guide to allow me to perform data analytics on the server using a Jupyter notebook remotely on my laptop: https://amber-md.github.io/pytraj/latest/tutorials/remote_jupyter_notebook

I am able to successfully load my Jupyter notebook on my laptop and perform analytics on the server. I can also mark my completed app as `.servable()` in the notebook and then use `panel serve --show ...` on ther VM terminal to serve the completed interactive app to LAN users via a web browser.

My issue is that when I instead mark my app with `.show()` to allow me to view the app/report that I am currently working on in the notebook, I get the following message outputted: `<bokeh.server.server.Server at 0x7faa92ef5590>` but the app does not load in a new browser tab as expected.

How can I make `app.show()` work when using a Jupyter notebook remotely instead of locally?

---

**Update 23/01/20 in response to @SandervandenOord's answer:**
"*You need to specify the port to .show() and make sure the user can access that port on the remote server*"

For the illustration of this question(not actuals), say my server VM is address **192.168.0.1** and my laptop is **192.168.0.2** and the port that I want to use with `app.show()` is **3333**.


1. **Setup the port:**

On the server (**192.168.0.1**):

- Check that **port 3333** is not being used:
   
  `sudo lsof -i:3333`
- Check that iptables aren't showing the port as open:
   
  `sudo iptables-save | grep 3333`
- Add the port to **/etc/services** file:
   
  `sudo nano /etc/services`
- I added the following line to the top of the file and saved:

```py
# service-name  port/protocol  [aliases ...]   [# comment]
bokeh-server    3333/tcp                        # Open port to allow app.show() to work on a remotely executed Jupyter Notebook
```

- Enable the firewall:
  `sudo systemctl enable firewalld`
- Start the firewall:
  `sudo systemctl start firewalld`
- Check the status of the firewall:
  `sudo systemctl status firewalld`
- Confirm that this port is now open:
  `sudo iptables-save | grep 3333`
  Output:
  `-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3333 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`

  2. **Test that the user can access the port on the server:**

I installed **ncat** on the server (**192.168.0.1**):
`sudo yum install nmap-ncat -y`

Then I set up messaging between the server and my laptop:

- On server:
   
  `nc -l 3333`
- On laptop:
  `nc 192.168.0.1 3333`

and also between the laptop and the server:

- On laptop:
   
  `nc -l 3333`
- On server:
  `nc 192.168.0.2 3333`
- Messages successfully make it from server to laptop and vice versa.
- Confirmation of these two connections:
  `sudo lsof -i:3333`

which outputted:

```py
COMMAND  PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nc      1776       XXX    5u  IPv4  23627      0t0  TCP vmserver:bokeh-server->192.168.0.2:55358 (ESTABLISHED)
nc      1846       XXX    3u  IPv4  22895      0t0  TCP vmserver:33658->192.168.0.2:bokeh-server (ESTABLISHED)
```

showing that the server on port 3333 can communicate with the laptop on a different port and the laptop on port 3333 can communicate with the server on a different port.

I'm not sure how to make them connect on the same port though? ie both on port 3333? Is this the source of my issue?

3. **Then in my jupyter notebook, I replaced `app.show()` with**

```py
app.show(port=3333, websocket_origin=None, threaded=False)
```

However I am still experiencing the same behaviour as previously in that the app does not load in a new browser tab as expected.

I then experimented with parameters `websocket_origin` (tried "192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2" and "*") and `threaded` (True/False) but changing these didn't give my desired result of the app loading in a new browser tab.

**A couple of interesting points**:


 1. If I run my notebook which executes

```py
app.show(port=3333, websocket_origin=None, threaded=False)
```

and then on the server run:
`sudo lsof -i:3333`
 then the following is returned:

```py
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ZMQbg/1 19328 xxx   45u  IPv4  83214      0t0  TCP *:bokeh-server (LISTEN)
ZMQbg/1 19328 xxx   54u  IPv6  83215      0t0  TCP *:bokeh-server (LISTEN)
```

It seems like the server is waiting for something to happen on port 3333? ie **LISTEN**? Unlike when I was messaging between the server and my laptop (and vice versa) there doesn't actually seem to be an **ESTABLISHED** connection though.

Please note that those 2 lines above only appear **after** I run the notebook.

2. After I have executed my notebook (and the app in the new tab hasn't opened), if I try to execute the notebook again then I get this warning in my jupyter notebook:
   `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

So it does seem like the connection between the server and laptop has been **ESTABLISHED** or at very least reserved? To fix this, I then have to close the connection to my server and then on my laptop run the command:
`lsof -ti:8888 | xargs kill -1` before then reestablishing my connection between the server and my laptop as per https://amber-md.github.io/pytraj/latest/tutorials/remote_jupyter_notebook

@SandervandenOord do you have any pointers as to what I could try next?

Many thanks in advance.

---

Software versions on the conda environment on the VM:

```py
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2019.03                  py37_0  
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
arrow-cpp                 0.11.1          py37h0e61e49_1004    conda-forge
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0  
astropy                   4.0              py37h7b6447c_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
beautifulsoup4            4.8.2                    py37_0  
bitarray                  1.2.0            py37h7b6447c_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd408876_0  
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py37_0  
boost-cpp                 1.68.0            h11c811c_1000    conda-forge
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.3.1            py37hdd07704_0  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2019.11.28           hecc5488_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
cartopy                   0.17.0           py37hbb7e04d_1  
certifi                   2019.11.28               py37_0  
cffi                      1.13.2           py37h2e261b9_0  
cftime                    1.0.4.2          py37hdd07704_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0  
cligj                     0.5.0                    py37_0  
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0  
colorcet                  2.0.2                      py_0    pyviz
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0  
cryptography              2.8              py37h1ba5d50_0  
curl                      7.67.0               hbc83047_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.14          py37he6710b0_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py37h7b6447c_0  
dask                      2.9.1                      py_0  
dask-core                 2.9.1                      py_0  
datashader                0.9.0                      py_0    pyviz
datashape                 0.5.4                    py37_1  
dbus                      1.13.12              h746ee38_0  
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
distributed               2.9.1                      py_0  
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h7b6447c_0  
feather-format            0.4.0                   py_1003    conda-forge
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
fiona                     1.8.4            py37hc38cc03_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
freexl                    1.0.5                h14c3975_0  
fribidi                   1.0.5                h7b6447c_0  
fsspec                    0.6.2                      py_0  
gdal                      2.3.3            py37hbb2a789_0  
geopandas                 0.6.1                      py_0  
geos                      3.7.1                he6710b0_0  
geoviews                  1.6.6                      py_0    pyviz
geoviews-core             1.6.6                      py_0    pyviz
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0  
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h7b6447c_0  
giflib                    5.1.4                h14c3975_1  
glib                      2.63.1               h5a9c865_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h10f8cd9_2  
graphite2                 1.3.13               h23475e2_0  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h7b6447c_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h7918eee_0  
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0  
hdf4                      4.2.13               h3ca952b_2  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
holoviews                 1.12.7                     py_0    pyviz
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
hvplot                    0.5.2                      py_0    pyviz
hypothesis                4.54.2                   py37_0  
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imageio                   2.6.1                    py37_0  
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0  
importlib_metadata        1.3.0                    py37_0  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      243  
ipykernel                 5.1.3            py37h39e3cac_1  
ipython                   7.11.1           py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.15.2                   py37_0  
jeepney                   0.4.2                      py_0  
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0  
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
json-c                    0.13.1               h1bed415_0  
json5                     0.8.5                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py37_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py37_0  
jupyterlab                1.2.4              pyhf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0  
kealib                    1.4.7                hd0c454d_6  
keyring                   20.0.0                   py37_0  
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37he6710b0_0  
krb5                      1.16.4               h173b8e3_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libarchive                3.3.3                h5d8350f_5  
libboost                  1.67.0               h46d08c1_4  
libcurl                   7.67.0               h20c2e04_0  
libdap4                   3.19.1               h6ec2957_0  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgdal                   2.3.3                h2e7e64b_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libkml                    1.3.0                h590aaf7_4  
liblief                   0.9.0                h7725739_2  
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h11d0813_2  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libpq                     11.2                 h20c2e04_0  
libprotobuf               3.6.1             hdbcaa40_1001    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libspatialindex           1.9.3                he6710b0_0  
libspatialite             4.3.0a              hb08deb6_19  
libssh2                   1.8.2                h1ba5d50_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_0  
libtool                   2.4.6                h7b6447c_5  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hea5a465_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h7d1a2b0_0  
llvmlite                  0.31.0           py37hd408876_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.4.2            py37hefd8a0e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h14c3975_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2  
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h5429711_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h7b6447c_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      243  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37hd6b4f25_0  
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0  
more-itertools            8.0.2                      py_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                hdf1c602_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37hfd86e86_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
netcdf4                   1.4.2            py37h808af73_0  
networkx                  2.4                        py_0  
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  6.0.2                    py37_0  
numba                     0.47.0           py37h962f231_0  
numexpr                   2.7.0            py37h9e4a6bb_0  
numpy                     1.17.4           py37hc1035e2_0  
numpy-base                1.17.4           py37hde5b4d6_0  
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openjpeg                  2.3.0                h05c96fa_1  
openpyxl                  3.0.2                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1d               h7b6447c_3  
owslib                    0.18.0                     py_0  
packaging                 20.0                       py_0  
pandas                    0.25.3           py37he6710b0_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
panel                     0.7.0                      py_0    pyviz
pango                     1.42.4               h049681c_0  
param                     1.9.2                      py_0    pyviz
parquet-cpp               1.5.1                         3    conda-forge
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0  
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0  
patchelf                  0.10                 he6710b0_0  
path                      13.1.0                   py37_0  
path.py                   12.4.0                        0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    7.0.0            py37hb39fc2d_0  
pip                       19.3.1                   py37_0  
pixman                    0.38.0               h7b6447c_0  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
plotly                    4.4.1                      py_0    plotly
plotly_express            0.4.1                      py_0    plotly
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
poppler                   0.65.0               h581218d_1  
poppler-data              0.4.9                         0  
proj4                     5.2.0                he6710b0_1  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.9                    py37_0  
psutil                    5.6.7            py37h7b6447c_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.8.1                      py_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h7725739_2  
pyarrow                   0.11.1          py37hbbcf98d_1002    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h14c3975_9  
pyct                      0.4.6                      py_0    pyviz
pyct-core                 0.4.6                      py_0    pyviz
pycurl                    7.43.0.3         py37h1ba5d50_0  
pyepsg                    0.4.0                    py37_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0  
pykdtree                  1.3.1            py37hdd07704_2  
pylint                    2.4.4                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.27           py37he6710b0_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0  
pyproj                    1.9.6            py37h14380d9_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h05f1152_2  
pyrsistent                0.15.6           py37h7b6447c_0  
pyshp                     2.1.0                      py_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.6.1            py37h71ec239_0  
pytest                    5.3.2                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.7.0                      py_0  
pytest-astropy-header     0.1.1                      py_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.5.0                      py_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.6                h0371630_2  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
pyviz_comms               0.7.2                      py_0    pyviz
pywavelets                1.1.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
pyyaml                    5.2              py37h7b6447c_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37he6710b0_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_1  
retrying                  1.3.3                    py37_2  
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0  
rtree                     0.8.3                    py37_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py37h7b6447c_0  
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37he6710b0_0  
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py37hd81dba3_0  
scipy                     1.3.2            py37h7c811a0_0  
seaborn                   0.9.0              pyh91ea838_1  
secretstorage             3.1.1                    py37_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                44.0.0                   py37_0  
shapely                   1.6.4            py37h86c5351_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.13.0                   py37_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
soupsieve                 1.9.5                    py37_0  
sphinx                    2.3.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0  
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.12           py37h7b6447c_0  
sqlite                    3.30.1               h7b6447c_0  
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37hdd07704_0  
sympy                     1.5.1                    py37_0  
tbb                       2019.8               hfd86e86_0  
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.3                    py37_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
thrift-cpp                0.12.0            h0a07b25_1002    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
tqdm                      4.41.1                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h14c3975_0  
urllib3                   1.25.7                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h7b6447c_0  
wurlitzer                 2.0.0                    py37_0  
xarray                    0.14.1                     py_1  
xerces-c                  3.2.2                h780794e_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.7                      py_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
zeromq                    4.3.1                he6710b0_3  
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

Comment: It's best to contact the devs of panel pyviz for this question. This can be done by posting your question here: https://discourse.holoviz.org/ or asking for help here: https://gitter.im/pyviz/pyviz They are usually very kind and willing to help. If you do find an answer, please be so kind to also post the solution here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the port to .show() and make sure the user can access that port on the remote server:

```
Signature: .show(port=0, websocket_origin=None, threaded=False)
Docstring:
Starts a bokeh server and displays the Viewable in a new tab

Arguments
---------
port: int (optional, default=0)
  Allows specifying a specific port
websocket_origin: str or list(str) (optional)
  A list of hosts that can connect to the websocket.

  This is typically required when embedding a server app in
  an external web site.

  If None, "localhost" is used.
threaded: boolean (optional, default=False)
  Whether to launch the Server on a separate thread, allowing
  interactive use.

Returns
-------
server: bokeh.server.Server or threading.Thread
  Returns the bokeh server instance or the thread the server
  was launched on (if threaded=True)
```